# How to return things with newline? (python)

Tags: python, flask, return

I am making a flask project right now and I need to return multiple values from a   function. Here is my code:

```
return  f"Title: {volume_info['title']}" \
        f"Author: {prettify_author}" \
        f"Page Count: {volume_info['pageCount']}" \
        f"Publication Date: {volume_info['publishedDate']}"
```

Here is my output:
[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNkMU.png)

It is all on one line, but I would like all the sections to be on different lines. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is going to a file or to the console, you can use a newline character:

```
return  f"Title: {volume_info['title']}\n" \
        f"Author: {prettify_author}\n" \
        f"Page Count: {volume_info['pageCount']}\n" \
        f"Publication Date: {volume_info['publishedDate']}\n"
```

If you're sending the output to a web browser, you'll need to do something different, like an HTML line break:

```
return  f"Title: {volume_info['title']}<br/>" \
        f"Author: {prettify_author}<br/>" \
        f"Page Count: {volume_info['pageCount']}<br/>" \
        f"Publication Date: {volume_info['publishedDate']}<br/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a triple-quote string to make multiline strings.  Everything between the triple quotes, including newlines, is included in the string:

```py
def format_data(volume_info, prettify_author):
    return f'''Title: {volume_info['title']}
Author: {prettify_author}
Page Count: {volume_info['pageCount']}
Publication Date: {volume_info['publishedDate']}'''

volume_info = {'title': 'Some Title',
               'pageCount': 5,
               'publishedDate': '01/01/2022'}

print(format_data(volume_info, 'John Doe'))
```

Output:

```
Title: Some Title
Author: John Doe
Page Count: 5
Publication Date: 01/01/2022
```